# Sending nested java object as JSON to Jersey Server

Tags: java, android, jersey, jersey-client

I'm using Jersey framework for sending/receiving data. In most of cases i don't have any problem with it but i want to send a complex nested java object to server. let me show you.

I've got two Entity.

```
public class Person implements Serializable
{
    private int age;
    private String name;
    private List<Certificate> certificates;
    // getter and setter
}

public class Certificate implements Serializable
{
    private long id;
    private String name;
    // getters and setters
}
```

My Client code is like following code

```
private static void sendObjectAsJson() throws Exception
{
     Client client = Client.create();
     WebResource webResource = client.resource("http://localhost:9990");

     // creating object
     Person person = new Person();
     person.setName("Eloy");
     person.setAge(25);

     ArrayList<Certificate> certificates = new ArrayList<>();
     certificates.add(new Certificate(1,"Java"));
     certificates.add(new Certificate(2,"Oracle"));
     certificates.add(new Certificate(3,"GNU Linux"));

     person.setCertificates(certificates);

     // convert java object to json string
     ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
     String personAsJsonString = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(person);

     ClientResponse response = webResource.path("/service/receiveObjectAsJson")
                    .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .post(ClientResponse.class, personAsJsonString);

            // 201 is defined in server as an error
            if (response.getStatus() != 201)
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : " + response.getStatus());

            String output = response.getEntity(String.class);

            System.out.println("Output from Server ...");
            System.out.println(output);
}
```

and my Server code is like:

```
 @POST
 @Path("/receiveObjectAsJson")
 @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
 @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
 public Response receiveObjectAsJson(Person person)
 {
     System.out.println("receiveObjectAsJson executed ...");
     System.out.println("data received");
     System.out.println("name: " + person.getName());
     System.out.println("age: " + person.getAge());

     if(person.getCertificates() != null && person.getCertificates().size() >=1 )
     {
         for (Certificate certificate : person.getCertificates())
         {
             System.out.println("Certificate ID: " + certificate.getId());
             System.out.println("Certificate Name: " + certificate.getName());
          }
      }

     String result = "thank you buddy";
     return Response.status(201).entity(result).build();
 }
```

Unfortunately I will get an error, please notice that I know that we can convert an object to JSON String, Send it to server and then in server parse it and create corresponding Java object. but i want to do it automatically because I can do the same thing when `Person` object does not consist of `Certificate ArrayList` and every thing works fine.

The error that i get is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed : HTTP error code : 400
    at JerseyClientGet.sendObjectAsJson(JerseyClientGet.java:193)
    at JerseyClientGet.main(JerseyClientGet.java:209)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

Comment: Are there any error logs on server side?

Comment: @Ilmo Euro no ! nothing will be print on the server, every thing looks fine. maybe it's good to test code on your self computer, i don't know...